# Scheme - How to read the string in cond

Tags: string, conditional-statements, scheme, user-input

I just want to know if its possible to read the string in Scheme like, `code == "SST"`

This is my code: 
`(display "Enter the Code")` 
`(define code(read))`

`(display "Quantity:")` 
`(define qty(read))`

`(cond`
 `((= code 1)(define price 20.00))` Only the number could be read
 `((= code LST)(define price 25.00))` I tried this, but nothing happend
 `(else 0)`
`)`

`(define total(* price qty))`
`(display "Total Price:")`
`(display total)`

If the user input "SST", it will equals to price 20.00, while "LST" equals to price 25.00 
I use Repl.it as a compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read` doesn't read strings or bytes. It reads Scheme code and it returns Scheme code as data. eg. if you enter `"SST"` it becomes the string `"SST"`, however if you enter `SST` it will read in the symbol `SST`.

`=` will only work for numbers. If you try to compare a non number with `=` the program might stop. You may use `equal?` to compare stuff that should look the same and it also works for numbers.

`define` cannot be anywhere. If you put it top level it will become globals and if you put it in `let`, `procedures` or the like they will become local bindings. Thu you have two possible solutions:

```
;; make cond the expression
(define price 
  (cond 
    ((equal? code 1) 20.0)
    ((equal? code 'LST) 25.0)
    (else 0)))

;; define it once, set! it from other places
(define price 0)
(cond 
  ((equal? code 1) (set! price 20.0))
  ((equal? code 'LST) (set! price 25.0)))
```